# Why process.memoryUsage() doesn't output the consumed memory of the node process

Tags: node.js, memory

In node.js application, I use the code 'console.log(process.memoryUsage());' to log the memory  usage. The output is as below.

```
{ rss: 13664256, heapTotal: 6131200, heapUsed: 3396912 }
```

When I use the process monitor to check the memory usage of the node process. The memory size is 14.5M.

I have a couple of questions.

1. What do the rss, heapTotal and heapUsed mean?
2. Why process.memoryUsage() output a memory usage value which is same as that shown in the process monitor?

====UPDATE 6/19/2013===

My OS is Mac OS X snow leopard.

Regards,

Jeffrey

Comment: You should at least specify the platform you're using and the specific counter from the "process monitor" you're comparing the rss value to. Determining the amount of memory a process uses is surprisingly complicated problem with many valid solutions. For future reference, node uses uv_resident_set_memory() to get its rss number: https://github.com/joyent/node/search?q=uv_resident_set_memory&ref=cmdform

Answer (score 0):

**What do the rss, heapTotal and heapUsed mean?**

[This article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/node-usage/) has a very effective answer. All memory related to nodejs belongs to something called a "resident set". A subset of the resident set is the heap, which stores the data composing javascript objects (Strings, Objects, etc.). The `rss` property stands for "resident set size". The `heapTotal` and `heapUsed` properties tell you the maximum size of the heap (the total amount of memory available for storing object data), and how much of the heap your nodejs app has consumed.