# How do I get the instance memory in use for a Node-Express App running in CloudFoundry?

Tags: node.js, memory, express, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I am currently building an app with a node-express backend and deploying it to CloudFoundry. I know I can get the total instance memory from the VCAP_APPLICATION var and I am able to get the OS memory using the 'os' module. It seems that I can get the application memory using the 'util' module, but none of the parameters of the returned object from process.memoryUsage() seem to be what I'm looking for. I am doing the following to get all that:

```
// Modules I've tried
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    os = require("os"),
    util = require("util");

// Memory statistics I can get -> cannot get instance memory in use
var memLimit = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_APPLICATION)['limits']['mem'];
    totalMem = os.totalmem(),
    freeMem = os.freemem(),
    memUsed = util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()).split(" "),
    heapUsed = memUsed[6],
    heapTotal = memUsed[4].substr(0,memUsed[4].length-1);
    rss = memUsed[2].substr(0,memUsed[2].length-1);
```

Does anyone know how I can use the heap/rss values or any other modules to get what I am looking for?

Comment: I saw this similar question, but noticed it was never answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170742/why-process-memoryusage-doesnt-output-the-consumed-memory-of-the-node-process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways of potentially accomplishing this.

If you don't necessarily need to get this value within your app, the `cf` utility can tell you how much memory your process is using.

Running `cf app <app-name>` will provide stats about the given app, one of which is memory usage.

In the case that you need this from your app code, you could try the [`node-memwatch`](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch) package. It can periodically emit events with stats about memory usage.

You could also take a look at the code `node-memwatch` uses to see how they compute the values.

Be careful, though. Memory profiling can be expensive, so watch what and how it's implemented.

Comment: Thanks Matt! That heap diffing method in memwatch is exactly what I was looking for.